# Nausea or vomiting

Tags: health

Is nausea or vomiting ever mentioned anywhere in the bible?  Please provided references.  I am unsure how I can make the question clearer.  I don't think it is in there.

Comment: https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=vomit&resultspp=100&version=NIV

Comment: The link provided by curiousdannii answers your question.  I suggest you take our Tour to find out what we look for in questions that show some evidence of research you have already done: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

Rev 3:16 comes to mind:  So because you are lukewarm, and neither cold nor hot, I will vomit you out of My mouth.